# "свеч" and "свечей" - what is the correct version

Tags: грамматика, существительные, склонение

I have been thinking about for a while, but didn't come to any conclusion.
What is the correct version for "свечи" (plural for "свеча") in the genitive?

> "Как расстанешься, если каждый вечер, лишь только нальются нити лампы в 50 свечей, и в зелёной тени абажура я могу писать и читать, в тепле, не помышляя о том, что на дворе ветерок при 18 градусах мороза".
>
> "Игра не стоит свеч".
>
> " Игра стоит свеч, то есть, идет хорошо настолько, что свечей не жаль."
>
> "Каталог свечей зажигания и накаливания", "Магия свеч и ангелы", etc.

Comment: "Игра (не) стоит свеч" is an idiom. "Свечей" is more appropriate in other cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно и так и так, [вот](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0) цитата.

> Существительное, неодушевлённое, женский род, 1-е склонение (тип склонения 4f по классификации А. Зализняка).
>   Встречается также вариант склонения по схеме 4d (мн. ч. све́чи, све́ч, све́чам, све́чи, све́чами, све́чах).

4f - [это как](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%3a%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0) раз `-е́й`

Соотношение [свеч](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%22&lr=213) / [свечей](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87e%D0%B9%22&lr=213) в Яндексе, впрочем, меньше, чем 1 к 5, то есть `свечей` говорят чаще.  Это не какая-то новая тенденция, употребление обеих форм и перевес в сторону второй формы прослеживается по меньшей мере с 19-го века.

**English summary:**
Both `свеч` and `свечей` are appropriate, though first form is 5-6 times as rare. This is not a new tendency, both forms are valid and completely interchangeable since at least the 19<sup>th</sup> century.

Comment: Could you please translate you answer into English (since the question was in English)? Or at least stick to one language throughout the post :) Thanks!

Comment: цитировать розенталя без перевода мы можем, но тут конечно другой случай))) могу конечно, но минут где-то уже через час-другой - буду в дороге.

Comment: If you exclude idiom "Игра не стоит свеч" from search results you will get about 1/11 ratio.

Comment: @hazzik, this is a valid note, didn't think about it :)